# How to halt matlab plot3 scale

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to plot pendulum (which changes position) using `plot3` function. Unfortunately, when my dot changes position in loop and is being plotted again, the scale of 3d plot is changing too, so the x axis depending on position changes (depending on position of the dot it can be from -1 to -1.5 or from -1 to -3) and y changes also. Only z states the same. The result is that the dot jumps on graph and does not create impression of pendulum. This is how I plot:

```
plot3(0,0,0);
daspect([1,1,1]);
axis([-10, 10, -10, 10]);
scatter3(x(i)-rs, y(i)-rs, 0);
```

I tried to deal with the problem using:

```
gca
```

or

```
set(fig, 'PaperPositionMode', 'auto');
```

but both do not help. I am also not able to rotate the graph, because it is being plotted and comes back to previous position.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `XLim`, `YLim`, and `ZLim` properties before plotting.  For example,

```
xlim=[-1 1];
```

or

```
haxe = gca;
haxe.XLim = [-1 1];
```

Also, you could set `XLimMode`, `YLimMode`, and `ZLimMode` properties to `manual`. For example,

```
haxe.XLimMode = 'manual'
```

For more information regarding axis properties see MATLAB's documentation for [axis properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example in 2D, you can easily apply this also to 3D:

```
N = 50;
x = [1:N;N:-1:1];
x = repmat(x,2,1).';
p = plot(x(1),1,'ob','MarkerFaceColor','b');
xlim([0 51])
for k = 2:numel(x)
    p.XData = x(k);
    drawnow
end
```

The key here is to set `xlim` before the loop, and then only update the relevant data in the plot (using `XData` in this case).